# SilverStripe SiteConfig titlefield manipulation

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've set up a `SiteConfig` extension (declared in yml, tested and confirmed) through which I'm trying to change the `Title` field (the one for Site title) to a read only field.

I know that in the parent class `SiteConfig` the `Title` Field is stored in a variable. **SiteConfig** line 85: `$titleField = new TextField("Title", _t('SiteConfig.SITETITLE', "Site title"))`

So in my extension `SiteConfigTweaks extends DataExtensions` I've tried:

```
 public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
     $titleField->performReadonlyTransformation();
 }
```

But this doesn't do the trick. What am I missing here?

Comment: That is your actual code? That should error out, since `$titleField` isn't defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
{
    if ($titleField = $fields->dataFieldByName('Title')) {
        $fields->replaceField(
            'Title', 
            $titleField->performReadonlyTransformation()
        );
    }
}
```

First you get the existing Title-field and also check for its existence. Then you replace the field with its read-only transformed variant.

Comment: That works, thanks bummzack. Small follow-up question since I need to learn more about all these field manipulation functions: How to set the value of this field to `DataObject::get("SomeObject")->first()->SomeColumn`? I thought I read about `setValue()` somewhere but it doesn't apply to `TextField`.

Comment: @Faloude `TextField` is a form field. Fields of a DataObject are of type `DBField`. It's not the same thing. `setValue` can be used on form-fields. For DB-fields you use `setField` on the DataObject or just normal assignments (eg. `$myDataObject->Field = 'value';`)

Comment: Oh yes I'm aware of the difference, my goal is to set the value of this read only field to something that is extracted from the database. Suppose I want to change the value of this `titleField` to `'Hello world'`, where should I place define `$titleField->setValue('Hello world')`? Later I will replace *Hello World* with a string extracted from the DB

Comment: @Faloude Just before you do the `performReadonlyTransformation`, eg. before the `$fields->replaceField(` line in the code above… have you tried that?

Comment: I've tried the following, **within** the `if` statement, **before** the `$fields->replaceField()`... `$titleField->setValue('Test');` No luck unfortunately

Comment: That's probably because the field value is loaded from the SiteConfig value from the DB. If the field should show a different value, you're better off removing the title field completely and add a new field with a different name. Eg. `$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', ReadonlyField::create('_Title', 'Title', 'Value'));`